# Django-CMS plugin not working

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've been working a Django-CMS plugin that uses the Flickr API, and after much debugging I finally got it working (locally). Once i migrated it to my server, it kept throwing this error on the edit page:

The main part is :

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/cms/page/2/edit/500.shtml/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int(): 2/edit/500.shtml
```

The odd thing is that it works perfectly locally, and this error is given when the CMS is rendering the plugin. To try to solve this I've tried creating the 500.html in my public_html folder, I've also created a 500.shtml one, but still doesn't work, btw I've always had my 500.html template in the root template folder.

I'm using Python 2.4, Django-CMS 2.1.3, Django 1.2, in server and the same locally except for python which is 2.6 locally, I've tested all my code in both local and server shells and it works perfectly fine.

EDIT: After examining the traceback I see that for some reason the object_id variable that django_cms uses for database querys, gets changed from '2' to '2/edit/500.shtml', but I still don't know whats causing this, please help.

thanks

Comment: What else do you have running on the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the Flickr API was not compatible with Python 2.4, upgrading to Python 2.7 solved this problem.